# visible text on a webpage not coming through Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

This code seems to work for almost all webpages i want to scrape, but for this webpage :- https://www.usana.com/ux/dotcom/#!/enu-US/contact , it is giving just one line of text, whereas , on the webpage, i can see many addresses are given:-

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()    # for cookies
options.add_argument(r"C:\Users\XXXXX\Selenium")  # this is the directory for the cookies
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXXX\Documents\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(100)
driver.get("https://www.usana.com/ux/dotcom/#!/enu-US/contact")

time.sleep(30)
try:
    click_alert=driver.switch_to.alert()      # to click on the pop up window
    click_alert.accept()
except:
    pass
res = requests.get(driver.current_url,headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
txt = soup.text
print(txt)
```

I have tried to handle the cookies agreement message and the pop up window that appears on the page, but it still produces just the one line of output as below :-

```
USANA Health Sciences
```

I am seeking to have all the addresses on this page as text.

What need to be added or edited in the above code ? Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use driver.page_source for BeautifulSoup. The reason being the
URI fragment (everything after the # in the URL) is not sent to the server so you need a browser to render the page presumably using JavaScript (requests doesn't send it and doesn't execute JavaScript so the page doesn't render as expected).

> Clients are not supposed to send URI fragments to servers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"C:\Users\XXXXX\Selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXXX\Documents\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(100)
driver.get("https://www.usana.com/ux/dotcom/#!/enu-US/contact")

time.sleep(3)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'OK')]").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Alert already accepted")
try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("optanon-allow-all").click()
except ElementNotInteractableException:
    print("Cookies already accepted")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
headers = [x.get_text(separator=" ").strip() for x in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'card-header'})]
bodies = [x.get_text(separator=" ").strip() for x in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'card-body'})]
print(list(zip(headers, bodies)))
driver.quit()
```

Outputs:

```
[('USANA Hong Kong', '5/F, Sino Plaza  255-257 Gloucester Road  Causeway Bay, Hong Kong    Customer Services Hotline: (852) 2162 1888  Order Express: (852) 2162 1800     Office Hours   Customer service  Monday–Friday 12:00 p.m.–9:00 p.m. (HKT)  Saturday 11:00 a.m.–4:00 p.m.  The office is closed on Sundays and public holidays. CustomerServiceHK@USANA.com'), ('USANA Japan', 'USANA Health Sciences Japan LLC. Ichigaya MS Bldg 2F 4-1-9 Kudankita, Chiyoda-ku Tokyo, Japan 102-0073 Contact Information Phone: 03-5215-3050 (Out of Japan: +81-3-5215-3050) Fax: 03-5215-3052 (Out of Japan: +81-3-5215-3052) Office Hours Customer Service: Monday–Friday 10:00 a.m. to 1:00 p.m., 2:00 p.m.to 6:00 p.m. Office Counter: Monday–Friday 13:00 - 19:00 CustomerServiceJP@USANA.com'), ('USANA Health Sciences Korea, Ltd.', '5F SI Tower 203, Teheran-ro, Gangnam-gu Seoul, Korea 06141 Tel: +82-2-2192-7300 Fax:+82-2-2192-7399 Customer Phone Service Line Business Hour Mon - Fri / 9:00 AM - 6:00 PM Sat / 9:00 AM - 1:00 PM (Closed Sun & Holiday) Customer Will-Call Service Line Business Hour Mon - Fri 9:00AM - 6:00PM (Closed Sat-Sun & Holiday) CustomerServiceKR@USANA.com'), ('USANA Taiwan', '7F, No. 99, Fu-Hsin N. Road,  Taipei 105, Taiwan,  Republic of China    Tel:+886-2-7724-8000  Fax: +886-2-7724-1000  Customer Service line: 0809-085-588  Customer Service Fax: 0809-085-500     Office Hours  Monday–Friday 9:00 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. (CST)  Closed weekends and national holidays.     Customer Service and Will Call  Monday–Friday 12:00 noon to 9:00 p.m.  Closed weekends and national holidays. CustomerServiceTW@USANA.com'), ('USANA Australia', '3 Hudson Avenue Castle Hill NSW 2154, Australia Customer Service Phone: +612 9842 4600 Toll-free: 1800 687 872 Sydney Business Center Opening Hours Mon 8:30 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Tue 8:30 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Wed 8:30 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Thu 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Fri 8:30 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Sat 9:30 a.m. to 3:00 p.m. Sundays and public holidays:Closed CustomerServiceANZ@USANA.com'), ('USANA Malaysia', 'USANA Malaysia UHS Essential Health (Malaysia) Sdn. Bhd. Unit M2-2 & M2-5, Level M2, The Vertical Podium Avenue 3, Bangsar South No. 8 Jalan Kerinchi 59200 Kuala Lumpur   Telephone: 603-2246 0800 Facsimile: 603-2246 0901 Office Hours Monday–Friday 11:30 a.m. to 7:30 p.m. (MYT) Saturday 10:30 a.m. to 1:30 p.m. Sundays and public holidays: Closed CustomerServiceMY@USANA.com'), ('USANA Philippines', 'UHS Essential Health Philippines, Inc. 24th Floor, Tower 1, The Enterprise Center, 6766 Ayala Avenue corner Paseo de Roxas, Makati City, Philippines 1200 Customer Service: (632) 858-4500 Phone Order Line (632) 858-4599 Fax Order Line Office Hours Business Center Monday-Friday 11:00am to 8:00pm Saturday 9:00 am to 1:00pm Customer Service Monday-Friday 11:00am to 8:00pm Saturday 9:00 am to 1:00pm CustomerServicePH@USANA.com'), ('USANA New Zealand', 'P.O. Box 17409, Greenlane 1546, AUCKLAND Level 1, 93 Ascot Avenue, Greenlane, Auckland 1051 Customer Service Phone: +64 9 415 2750 Toll-free: 0800 872 626 Auckland Business Center Opening Hours Mon 9:00 a.m. to 7:00 p.m. Tue 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Wed 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Thu 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Fri 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Sat 10:00 a.m. to 3:00 p.m. Sundays and public holidays: Closed customerserviceanz@usana.com'), ('USANA Health Sciences Singapore Pte Ltd', '391B Orchard Road, Ngee Ann City Tower B, #19-01/02 Singapore 238874 Customer Service: (65) 6820-8828 Fax: (65) 6820-7007 Business Hours: Mon to Fri - 1230hr to 2030hr Saturday - 1030hr to 1400hr Sunday / Public Holiday - Closed CustomerServiceSG@USANA.com'), ('USANA Health Sciences (Thailand) Ltd.', 'Unit 01-04  Chamchuri Square Building  319 Phyathai Road  Pathumwan, Bangkok 10330    Distributor Services: 02-761-4300     Customer Service and Will Call  Monday–Friday: 11.00 a.m.-8.00 p.m.  Saturday: 1.00 p.m.-5.00 p.m. Closed Sunday and national holidays CustomerServiceTH@USANA.com'), ('USANA Health Sciences Indonesia', 'Menara Jamsostek South Tower 14th Floor Jalan Gatot Subroto Kav 38 Jakarta 12710 Indonesia Contact Information Reception Phone: +62 21 278 38 600 Customer Service Call Center: 1500847 Customer Service Fax: +62 21 278 38 688 Office Hours Business Centre Monday to Friday: 11:00 a.m.–11:00 p.m. Saturday: 9:00 a.m.–6:00 p.m. Customer Service Monday to Friday: 11:00 a.m.–8:00 p.m. Saturday: 9:00 a.m.–1:00p.m Facebook https://www.facebook.com/officialusanaindonesia CustomerServiceID@USANA.com'), ('USANA Netherlands', 'USANA Health Sciences  92, avenue des Ternes  Paris, France 75017    Distributor Services: 0800-022-7288  Fax: 001-801-954-7240     Customer Service Hours  Monday through Friday  Reception, meeting rooms and will call: Tuesday, Thursday and Friday 12:30 p.m.–8:00 p.m.  Wednesday 12:30 pm – 4:00 pm.  Saturday 10:00 a.m.–5:00 p.m.  Call center: 9:00 a.m.– midnight (GMT+1). ContactEU@usana.com'), ('USANA United Kingdom', 'USANA United Kingdom  Customer service representatives located in Salt Lake City, Utah, support the Associates and Preferred Customers in the United Kingdom.    Customer Service: 08 08 234 4478    Fax: 08 08 234 2472     Opening Hours:  Monday – Friday (excluding some holidays) 1:30 p.m. to 2:00 a.m. (London time).     Customer Service Hours  Monday through Friday 6:30 AM to 9:00 PM MST. ContactEU@USANA.com'), ('USANA France/Belgium, Paris Office', 'USANA Europe (Paris Office) \n121 Av. Des Champs Élysées \n75008 Paris, France \nDoor Code: B152 \nOrder pick-up:  \nThursday 12:30 - 10:00pm \nFriday 12:30 - 8:00pm \nSaturday 12:30 - 7:00pm \nMeeting rooms upon reservation: \nRESERVATIONSsalles@fr.usana.com  \n \nCustomer Service:  \nFrance: +33 1 42 99 76 50  \nRomania: +40 312 295 242  \nGermany: 0800 1825899 \nBelgium: 0 800 14 432 \nSpain: 900 941 696  \nItaly: 800 790 241  \nUK: 08 08 234 4478 (calls to SLC office) contactEU@USANA.com'), ('USANA United States', '3838 West Parkway Boulevard  Salt Lake City, UT 84120     Receptionist and Investor Relations  Phone: 801-954-7100  Fax: 801-954-7300  Investor.Relations@us.usana.com  Hours: 9:00 am – 5:00 pm MST     Customer Service  Phone: 1-888-950-9595  Fax: 1-800-289-8081  Languages available: English, Spanish, French, Mandarin, Cantonese, & Korean  Hours: 6:30am – 9:00pm MST customerservice@usanainc.com'), ('USANA Puerto Rico', '3838 West Parkway Boulevard  Salt Lake City, UT 84120     Receptionist and Investor Relations  Phone: 801-954-7100  Fax: 801-954-7300  Investor.Relations@us.usana.com  Hours: 9:00 am – 5:00 pm MST     Customer Service  Phone: 1-888-950-9595  Fax: 1-800-289-8081  Languages available: English, Spanish, French, Mandarin, Cantonese, & Korean  Hours: 6:30am – 9:00pm MST customerservice@usanainc.com'), ('Caribbean', 'Customer Service (toll-free): 1-888-950-9595  Fax: 1-801-954-7300     Trinidad and Tobago    Customer Service (toll-free): 1-888-667-3574  Fax: 1-801-954-7300 The Dominican Republic    Customer Service (toll-free): 1-888-751-2425  Fax: 1-801-954-7300     Office Hours  Monday–Friday (excluding some holidays) 6:30 a.m.–9:00 p.m. (MST/MDT). The Caribbean is two hours ahead of Mountain Time. customerservice@usanainc.com'), ('USANA Canada, Ontario Office', '80 Innovation Dr.  Woodbridge, ON  L4H0T2  CANADA     Customer Service  Phone: 1-888-950-9595  Fax: 1-800-289-8081  Languages available: English, Spanish, French, Mandarin, Cantonese, & Korean  Hours: 6:30am – 9:00pm MST     Investor Relations  Phone: 801-954-7100  Fax: 801-954-7300  Investor.Relations@us.usana.com  Hours: 8:00 am – 6:00 pm MST   Office Hours Monday: 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m.*  Tuesday: 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m.*  Wednesday: 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Thursday: 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. Friday: 9:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m.* Office hours are in EDT/EST *Associates are asked to contact the office if they require assistance prior to 9 a.m. or after 5 p.m., as we will be pleased to make arrangements to accommodate them. customerservice@usanainc.com'), ('USANA Canada, Vancouver Office', 'Suite 2118, 13353 Commerce Parkway  Richmond, British Columbia  CANADA V6V 3A1     Customer Service  Phone: 1-888-950-9595  Fax: 1-800-289-8081  Languages available: English, Spanish, French, Mandarin, Cantonese, & Korean  Hours: 6:30am – 9:00pm MST     Investor Relations  Phone: 801-954-7100  Fax: 801-954-7300  Investor.Relations@us.usana.com  Hours: 8:00 am – 6:00 pm MST Office Hours \nMonday to Friday, 11:00 a.m. to 7:00 p.m. (PDT/PST) \n customerservice@usanainc.com'), ('USANA Mexico S.A. de C.V.', 'Av. paseo de las Palmas 525, piso no. 8  Col. Lomas de Chapultepec, Del. Miguel Hidalgo  México D.F. C.P. 11000    Reception: (55) 5093-9650  Distributor Services / Order Express: 01 800 08 USANA (87262)  Fax: 01 800 08 USANA (87262)     Office Hours  Monday–Friday 9:00 a.m. to 6:00 p.m. (CST/CDT)  Saturday 9:00 a.m. to 2:00 p.m. (CST/CDT)—Will Call only CustomerServiceMX@USANA.com'), ('USANA Health Sciences Colombia, S.A.S.', 'Calle 100 No. 13 - 76 Piso 4to  Torre Mansarovar  Bogotá D.C. Colombia     Main Office  Phone: (57) 1-546-3939  Fax: (57) 1-546-3951     Distributor Services  Phone: (57) 1-546-3939  Toll Free: 01 8000 963750  Fax: (57) 1-546-3950     Office Hours  Monday – Friday (Not holidays) / 9:00 a.m. – 6:00 p.m. COT  Saturday / 9:00 a.m. – 12:30 p.m. COT     Customer Service Hours  Monday - Friday 9:00 a.m. – 6:00 p.m. COT  Closed Sundays and Holidays CustomerServiceCO@USANA.com'), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', '')]
```

**Updated in response to comment**

If you want the complete text of the page replace the last four lines above with:

```
print(soup.get_text(separator=" ").strip())
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your solution is really helpful. But as mentioned, this is a piece of code from a code which scrapes multiple webpages, hence i can't mention class name. Any way to get the text only without class name?

Comment: I have updated my answer in response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found another way to solve this :-

```
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XXXXXX\XXXX\Documents\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(url)
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(100)
    time.sleep(3)
            
    try:
        click_alert=browser.switch_to.alert()
        click_alert.accept()
        wait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') , 'agree')]"))).click()
    except:
         pass
```